# Token valida archivos HTML

Tags: c#, angularjs, tokens

Colegas,
el escenario es así. Implemente un validación mediante tokens con `AngularJS` y `C#`; ya realice todo el trabajo en el back y front y esta funcionando bien.
Por motivos de curiosidad implemente un log que me entrega info de qué es lo que está validando mi token, y grande fue mi sorpresa al percatarme que **el interceptor también se llama para archivos html**.

Por ejemplo, tengo una pantalla de búsqueda donde al aplicar filtros muestro los datos en una tabla; dicha tabla es **[smart-table](https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)**, el cual como cualquier paquete de terceros tiene sus propias funciones. Pasa que al momento de entrar en dicha pantalla de búsqueda interceptor que implemente también hace validaciones a archivos HTML propios de esta librería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenía entendido que el token sólo funcionaba con request hacia APIS y no a archivos de este tipo; de ser así, *habría alguna forma de desactivar que pase también por HTML y se enfoque solamente en las llamadas a la API?*

Les adjunto mi código interceptor por si les sirve.

```
app.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['AuthToken', function (AuthToken) {
    let authInterceptorsFactory = [];

    authInterceptorsFactory.request = (config) => {
        const storage = AuthToken.getToken();

        if (storage) {
            if (storage.token)
                config.headers['Authorization'] = `bearer ${storage.token}`;
        }
        console.log(`[AuthInterceptor] : ${JSON.stringify(config)}`);
        return config;
    };

    return authInterceptorsFactory;
}]);
```

Como siempre, cualquier orientación o info se agradecerá mucho!

Comment: aunque intercepte los request a html en que afectaria que pongas un header con el token si simplemente lo deberia ignorar y retornar el html

Comment: No se realmente en que puede afectar eso, en rendimiento o algo más. Sólo que encuentro que el funcionamiento no es el correcto, nada más. Ignoro también si este comportamiento es normal o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que estas adjuntando el interceptor para que controles llamadas `http`, realizar un `GET` a una `url`, la cual retorne `html` no lo va a discriminar porque lo que controlas son los verbos `http`: GET, POST, PUT, etc

Obtener un html es como cualqueir otro request por eso no diferencia la accion sino lo haces explicitamente tu desde el codigo

Quiza si quieres aplicar una validacion podrias hacer uso del `Content-Type` para que valide si es `html`, `json`, etc los que se esta solicitando.
Una web api suele solicitar siempre json

```
if(config.headers[Content-Type] == 'application/json'){
   //agregas el token
}
```

No conozco muchos de ese componente de tabla que utilizas, pero seguramente haga uso de `$http` de angularjs por lo tanto tambien va as er interceptado

Comment: Muy buena opción Leandro!